# Can't change the list view

Tags: data-view-web-part

I created a NewView for a list. When I select that view by Edit Web Part>Selected View>NewView , the view doesn't change.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Has the view the same fields as the other view?
Maybe it changes but you dont see it?

Comment: fieldRef's are same ofcourse but there is extra Xsl part for the new view. When I add the xsl part to the normal view it's ok,it changes. But nothing happens when I select the view in WebPart Properties.